# Rpi CPU HW features baseline

Tags: pi-4, opencv, setup

I am trying to install opencv 3.4.12 in rpi4.

AFAIK, Enabling Neon flag can accelerate the performance.
But in cmake output I observe that Neon feature is not detected as CPU/HW feature.
(cmake ouput below)

```
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:
--       requested:                 NEON
--       disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON
```

Whereas when i run check CPU info i can see the neon flags.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : BCM2711
Revision    : b03114
Serial      : 100000005ce5f0a0
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

Can anyone point me what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the junk data you get from /proc/cpuinfo. It was broken by the Linux kernel developers.

Comment: So do you mean rpi4 doesnt have neon supported ? Or is there any update in kernal that can fix this ?

Comment: No. I mean that cpuinfo incorrectly reports what the CPU can do. Should get fixed with the switch to aarch64.

Comment: @Dougie I'm pretty certain the Pi 4 supports VFPV3 and NEON. If you claim the opposite, do you have any links for a reference?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm saying that the kernel reports it incorrectly for ARM8. But gets it right with AARCH64. Because the ARM support in the kernel is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18244) which is fixed in version 3.4.13. A possible workaround is to pass `-DENABLE_NEON` to `cmake`.

Comment: Thanks for pointer. I haven't checked the same...i will accept it as answer ASA i can get this working on my board. Thanks again.